# Pycharm duplicating file logging in console

Tags: python, logging, pycharm

Python 3.6.4 Pycharm 2017.3

I am trying to log to file at level=debug and to the console level=error but seem to be getting the file logs reflected in the run console (without the formatting) as well as the logs intended for the console.

I have the file set as an alias in the configuration menu. Logging to file is behaving as expected.

I lifted the logging configuration from a tutorial in the docs:

```
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create file handler which logs all debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('clsfr.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# create console handler with a higher log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# create formatter and add it to the handlers
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - 
%(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handlers to logger
LOGGER.addHandler(ch)
LOGGER.addHandler(fh)

# from logger calls
LOGGER.error("Test ERROR message")
LOGGER.debug("about to yield {} {}".format(number, year))
LOGGER.debug('iterator returned {} {}'.format(number, year))
LOGGER.info('Queued file key {} - count is {}'.format(id, count))
```

Some output to the console:  (all in red type)

```
2018-01-31 15:15:40,594 - __main__ - ERROR - Test ERROR message
ERROR:__main__:Test ERROR message
DEBUG:__main__:about to yield 02680309 2000
DEBUG:__main__:iterator returned 02680309 2000
INFO:__main__:Queued file key 02680309_2000_1 - count is 1
DEBUG:__main__:about to yield 02680309 2001
```

Corresponding output to file: (first line only in red)

```
2018-01-31 15:15:40,594 - __main__ - ERROR - Test ERROR message
2018-01-31 15:15:41,822 - __main__ - DEBUG - about to yield 02680309 
2000
2018-01-31 15:15:41,823 - __main__ - DEBUG - iterator returned 02680309 
2000
2018-01-31 15:15:41,823 - __main__ - INFO - Queued file key 
02680309_2000_1 - count is 1
2018-01-31 15:15:41,823 - __main__ - DEBUG - about to yield 02680309 
2001
```

I did some searching to try and diagnose which led me to run some lines of code in the console to see if there were multiple StreamHandlers but it would appear not:

```
        logging.getLogger().handlers
Out[6]: []
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        logger = logging.getLogger('temp')
        logger.handlers
Out[9]: []
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.handlers
Out[11]: [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>]
        fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
        fh
Out[13]: <FileHandler /Users/andyspence/Project/ccML_async/test.log 
         (NOTSET)>
        logger.addHandler(fh)
        logger.handlers
Out[15]: [<StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)>,
         <FileHandler /Users/andyspence/Project/ccML_async/test.log 
         (NOTSET)>]
```

Python error or a Pycharm configuration error ??

Comment: Running your simplified code (plus three logs info, debug, error) I got results like you wanted - one error on terminal, and three in file. Same with PyCharm 2016. Can you update question with logging statements?

Comment: Added the logging calls to the code. Looks like a Pycharm configuration issue then, the calls are routine enough.

Comment: If running from console/terminal yields results as expected - then there is no argument about that. If it turns out that it's still not working as expected then we can dig little more into it

Answer (score 0):

Results from the terminal were identical.

I had a look at my modules and deleted an unused logger definition.

The code then performed as expected